# can't ping/ssh new libvirt instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ping, libvirt

I have a working virtual host that was Ubuntu-Server Lucid (10.4).  I've been using it for a while and has several functional guests created on Lucid.

Today I upgraded to Maverick, then to Natty (11.4).  Upgrades went fine, all my old guests come up and function normally.

I created a new guest, and while it comes up, and appears to have no errors in the logs, I cannot ping or ssh into it.

$ virsh start stg-app2 (no errors)
...shows up in 'virsh list' as 'running'

I was able to cat the guest's interfaces file before it was converted to a qcow image (looks fine to me):

```
cat /tmp/somepath/etc/networking/interfaces

 # The primary network interface
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
         address 192.168.1.193
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         network 192.168.1.0
         broadcast 192.168.1.255
         gateway 192.168.1.1
         # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
         dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
         dns-search defaultdomain
```

Creation Log:

```
$ sudo vmbuilder kvm ubuntu \
>  --suite lucid \
>  --flavour virtual \
>  --arch amd64 \
>  --mem 512 \
>  --rootsize 8192 \
>  --swapsize 512 \
>  --name 'Josh Sharpe' \
>  --user jsharpe \
>  --pass ASDFASDFASDFASDF \
>  --hostname stg-app2 \
>  --ip 192.168.1.193 \
>  --mask 255.255.255.0 \
>  --net 192.168.1.0 \
>  --bcast 192.168.1.255 \
>  --gw 192.168.1.1 \
>  --addpkg openssh-server \
>  --libvirt qemu:///system

2011-09-18 15:46:17,114 INFO    : Calling hook: preflight_check
2011-09-18 15:46:17,173 INFO    : Calling hook: set_defaults
2011-09-18 15:46:17,174 INFO    : Calling hook: bootstrap
2011-09-18 15:59:43,753 INFO    : Calling hook: configure_os
2011-09-18 16:00:09,693 INFO    : update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for rsh.
2011-09-18 16:00:09,773 INFO    : update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for rlogin.
2011-09-18 16:00:09,852 INFO    : update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for rcp.
2011-09-18 16:00:11,354 INFO    : Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ...
2011-09-18 16:00:11,502 INFO    : Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ...
2011-09-18 16:00:12,023 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:00:12,023 INFO    : Warning: Fake initctl called, doing nothing
2011-09-18 16:00:12,023 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:00:12,023 INFO    : Warning: Fake initctl called, doing nothing
2011-09-18 16:00:16,148 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:00:16,149 INFO    : Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
2011-09-18 16:00:16,152 INFO    : Local time is now:      Sun Sep 18 20:00:16 UTC 2011.
2011-09-18 16:00:16,152 INFO    : Universal Time is now:  Sun Sep 18 20:00:16 UTC 2011.
2011-09-18 16:00:16,152 INFO    : 

Extracting templates from packages: 100%
2011-09-18 16:01:03,447 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:01:03,447 INFO    : Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
2011-09-18 16:01:03,449 INFO    : Local time is now:      Sun Sep 18 20:01:03 UTC 2011.
2011-09-18 16:01:03,449 INFO    : Universal Time is now:  Sun Sep 18 20:01:03 UTC 2011.
2011-09-18 16:01:03,449 INFO    : Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.
2011-09-18 16:01:03,449 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:02:06,239 INFO    : Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate ca-certificates.crt
2011-09-18 16:02:06,548 INFO    : 0 added, 1 removed; done.
2011-09-18 16:02:06,548 INFO    : Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
2011-09-18 16:02:12,893 INFO    : restart: Unknown instance: 
2011-09-18 16:02:13,535 INFO    : start: Unknown parameter: JOB
2011-09-18 16:02:15,191 INFO    : Calling hook: post_install
2011-09-18 16:02:15,191 INFO    : Cleaning up
2011-09-18 16:02:15,192 INFO    : Calling hook: preflight_check
2011-09-18 16:02:16,160 INFO    : Calling hook: configure_networking
2011-09-18 16:02:16,189 INFO    : Calling hook: configure_mounting
2011-09-18 16:02:16,197 INFO    : Calling hook: mount_partitions
2011-09-18 16:02:16,198 INFO    : Mounting target filesystems
2011-09-18 16:02:16,198 INFO    : Creating disk image: "/tmp/tmpIT5W5T" of size: 8704MB
2011-09-18 16:02:16,215 INFO    : Adding partition table to disk image: /tmp/tmpIT5W5T
2011-09-18 16:02:16,371 INFO    : Adding type 4 partition to disk image: /tmp/tmpIT5W5T
2011-09-18 16:02:16,372 INFO    : Partition at beginning of disk - reserving first cylinder
2011-09-18 16:02:16,408 INFO    : Adding type 3 partition to disk image: /tmp/tmpIT5W5T
2011-09-18 16:02:16,413 INFO    : [0] ../../libparted/filesys.c:148 (ped_file_system_type_get): File system alias linux-swap(new) is deprecated
2011-09-18 16:02:16,441 INFO    : Creating loop devices corresponding to the created partitions
2011-09-18 16:02:16,464 INFO    : Creating file systems
2011-09-18 16:02:16,520 INFO    : mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
2011-09-18 16:02:19,962 INFO    : mkswap: /dev/mapper/loop0p2: warning: don't erase bootbits sectors
2011-09-18 16:02:19,963 INFO    :         on whole disk. Use -f to force.

2011-09-18 16:02:22,590 INFO    : Calling hook: install_bootloader
2011-09-18 16:02:41,449 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2011-09-18 16:02:41,488 INFO    : Searching for default file ... Generating /boot/grub/default file and setting the default boot entry to 0
2011-09-18 16:02:41,489 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2011-09-18 16:02:41,493 INFO    : Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... 
2011-09-18 16:02:41,493 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:02:41,493 INFO    : Could not find /boot/grub/menu.lst file. 
2011-09-18 16:02:41,494 INFO    : Generating /boot/grub/menu.lst
2011-09-18 16:02:41,543 INFO    : Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
2011-09-18 16:02:41,657 INFO    : grep: /boot/config*: No such file or directory
2011-09-18 16:02:41,716 INFO    : Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
2011-09-18 16:02:41,716 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:02:41,997 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2011-09-18 16:02:42,023 INFO    : Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
2011-09-18 16:02:42,026 INFO    : Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
2011-09-18 16:02:42,100 INFO    : Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
2011-09-18 16:02:42,126 INFO    : grep: /boot/config*: No such file or directory
2011-09-18 16:02:42,189 INFO    : Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
2011-09-18 16:02:42,189 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:02:42,337 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2011-09-18 16:02:42,342 INFO    : Calling hook: install_kernel
2011-09-18 16:02:55,122 INFO    : Done.
2011-09-18 16:03:00,078 INFO    : Running depmod.
2011-09-18 16:03:00,133 INFO    : update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-33-server
2011-09-18 16:03:01,875 INFO    : Running postinst hook script /usr/sbin/update-grub.
2011-09-18 16:03:01,956 INFO    : Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
2011-09-18 16:03:01,983 INFO    : Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
2011-09-18 16:03:01,986 INFO    : Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
2011-09-18 16:03:02,046 INFO    : Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
2011-09-18 16:03:02,079 INFO    : Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-server
2011-09-18 16:03:02,152 INFO    : Replacing config file /var/run/grub/menu.lst with new version
2011-09-18 16:03:02,170 INFO    : Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
2011-09-18 16:03:02,170 INFO    : 
2011-09-18 16:03:03,040 INFO    : Calling hook: unmount_partitions
2011-09-18 16:03:03,040 INFO    : Unmounting target filesystem
2011-09-18 16:03:06,713 INFO    : Calling hook: convert
2011-09-18 16:03:06,714 INFO    : Converting /tmp/tmpIT5W5T to qcow2, format ubuntu-kvm/tmpIT5W5T.qcow2
2011-09-18 16:03:15,344 INFO    : Calling hook: fix_ownership
2011-09-18 16:03:15,345 INFO    : Calling hook: deploy
```

Startup Log:

/var/log/libvirt/qemu/stg-app2.log

```
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-0.14 -enable-kvm -m 512 -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -name stg-app2 -uuid 0c4d8375-49ae-9ddc-28ca-17ac3988ff4e -nodefconfig -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/stg-app2.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=readline -rtc base=utc -boot c -drive file=/home/jsharpe/stg-app2/ubuntu-kvm/tmpIT5W5T.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,format=qcow2 -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -netdev tap,fd=19,id=hostnet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:48:94:99,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -usb -vnc 127.0.0.1:3 -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4
```

Comment: Have you tried vnc'ing to it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in Natty you must specify the bridge (I guess it used to be assumed):

Add this option:

--bridge br0